# HighCharts navigator fillColor

Tags: highcharts

I have this:

```
this.chartOptions.navigator.series.fillColor = 'red';
```

And it works, but VS Code is throwing up an error:

```
Property 'fillColor' does not exist on type 'SeriesAbandsOptions | SeriesAdOptions | SeriesAoOptions | SeriesApoOptions | SeriesAreaOptions | ... 98 more ... | NavigatorSeriesOptions[]'.
  Property 'fillColor' does not exist on type 'SeriesAbandsOptions'.ts(2339
```

Can I safely ignore this warning?

Comment: Hi @Latcie, It is only a TS error, so you can ignore it. However, it looks like a Highcharts bug, in API we can read: `navigator.series ... Available options are the same as any series, documented at plotOptions and series.` so you can report it as an issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: I got around this by setting the type of option to "any" and not "Option".